# Jquery to amend href except where href is #

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to amend the links on my website to jump to a div when clicked with 2 exceptions, 1. when the link is index.php and 2. when the link already contains #.

I have got it working for the first instance using the code below.

```
$(function() { $('a').each(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('href').trim() == "index.php") {
         $(this).attr('href', 'index.php'); 
        } else {
            $(this).attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + "#bodyContent";
});
        }

    });
});
```

So at the moment if the link is `<a href='index.php'> </a>` then the link stays as it is. All other links have #bodyContent added. This means I am getting links that are #pt_sizes#bodyContent this is not good.

If I specify the exact # in the code as below it works for that link.

```
$(function() { $('a').each(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('href').trim() == "index.php") {
         $(this).attr('href', 'index.php'); 
        } else if ($(this).attr('href').trim() == "#pt_sizes") {
         $(this).attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
    return oldHref;
}); 
        } else {
            $(this).attr('href', function (_, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + "#bodyContent";
});
        }

    });
});
```

However I have 4 # links on one page and potentially more across the whole site so specifying for each eventuality doesn't work.

What are my options for getting around this?

Comment: this lets you know whether the url contains `#` or not: `else if ( $(this).attr('href').trim().includes('#') ) { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick, thanks